# Python: remove single quotation in a string in a list

Tags: string, python-3.x, replace

I have a list of items, `list1`, shown below:

```
["None", "A ','B", "A"]
```

The second element of `list1` is `"A ','B"`.

How can I remove the single quotation mark and get `"A, B"` instead?

Comment: Well - you could loop over it and just remove `'` eg: `list1 = [el.replace("'", '') for el in list1]` but that list looks like you've parsed something incorrectly somewhere earlier down the line?

Comment: Thanks Jon, it helped! I added list[i].replace("'", '') to my existing for loop.

Comment: @S.J, welcome to StackOverflow. If your problem has been solved, please accept an answer below. If you don't see a solution below, post it yourself and accept it, instead of editing your question with SOLVED. This will help others find answers faster. Also, try to put as much detail in your post as possible. There aren't any references to loops in your post, and your code shows you manually assigning a list to `list1`. Based off your comment above, it doesn't appear that your question reflects what you're actually having an issue with.

Comment: Thanks for feedbacks Joshua! I will improve my posts in the future :)

Comment: @S.J I look forward to seeing them, and helping where I can! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple string replace.

```
list1[1] = list1[1].replace("'","")
```

EDIT:
Strings are immutable, so you have to actually do the replace, and reassign. I should add, that by "removing" the single quote, you will not be gaining a space after the comma.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a single quote from all strings in a list, use a list comprehension like

```py
l = ["None", "A ','B", "A"]
l = [s.replace("'", '') for s in l]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/F7vuAW):

```py
l = ["None", "A ','B", "A"]
l = [s.replace("'", '') for s in l]
print(l) # => ['None', 'A ,B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ["None", "A ','B", "A"]
list1[1] = list1[1].replace("'", "")
print(list1)
```

Is that what you need?